# На python с помощью pymongo получить значения

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Мне нужно заполнить многомерный список с данными, хранящимися в MongoDB. Но мне выводит только название полей, а не сами значения, которые соответствуют этим полям.
P.S. Недавно начал учить пайтон и решил написать бота для телеги с подключением бд(Монго бд)

```
            collection = db.tel_numb
            rez = collection.find()
            list_rez = list(rez)
            for i in list_rez:
                for j in i:
                    print(j, end = ' ')
                print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я немного разобрался, и оказалось, что монго возвращает список словарей, на время создания вопроса не сталкивался ещё со словарями. Если у кого будет такая же задача - смотрите тему о словарях.